# Mule 3.9.1 database parameterized-query not returning data

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have the below flow reference: `<flow name="getAccountsFlow">
        <logger message="Type:&quot;#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.type]&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from flights_customers where accountType = "#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.type]"]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
</flow>`

The logger prints the variable value: `INFO  2019-01-07 16:08:51,270 [[assignment-accounts].accounts-api-httpListenerConfig.worker.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Type:"business"`

But the query returns 0 rows.

But when i use the variable transformer, then value can be accessed in the query as: `<flow name="getAccountsFlow">
        <logger message="Type:&quot;#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.type]&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-variable variableName="type" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.type]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from flights_customers where accountType = :type]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="type" type="VARCHAR" value="#[flowVars.type]" ></db:in-param>
        </db:select>
    </flow>`

why is the `#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.type]` not visible in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because of the double quotes around the expression in the query . Try removing those.

But it is safer to use placeholders because of injection anyway, so I would use the second example anyway in my opinion.